# Show Markov Chain is positive recurrent by proving expectation of first return time is finite

Tags: probability, summation, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**EDIT:** @Joe in the comments has shown that it is sufficient to calculate the return time of $x=0$ which I have done, and since the chain is recurrent, showing $x=0$ is positive recurrent implies the whole communication class (the full MC) is positive recurrent. However, I am still looking to explicitly solve the summations when $x\ne 0$.

> Consider the Markov Chain defined on the countably infinite state space, the non-negative integers, i.e $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ given by:
> $$\begin{cases}p(x,x+1)=3/4\\
> p(x,0)=1/4\end{cases}$$
> I want to show that it is positive recurrent and I'm trying to do it by showing showing that $\forall x, \, \mathbb{E}[T(x)]<\infty$ where $T(x)$ is the first return time to the state $x$.

An example of this process is seen by stacking blocks, where with probability $3/4$ the next block stably adds on the tower and $1/4$ probability for the next block to cause the tower to fall and to start over.

And no, it's not a homework problem, it *was*, and I proved it by showing the existence of an invariant measure, but I'm looking for something more direct.

1. How do I continue the proof method I am using?
2. I know showing the existence of an invariant measure proves its positive recurrent and I have found
   $$\pi(x)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x$$
   but I'm hoping to find a more direct proof like the one I'm using rather than using the implication of the invariant measure.

If my calculation for the invaraint measure is correct, I should expect to get
$$\mathbb{E}[T(x)] = \frac{1}{\pi(x)} = 4 \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^x$$

This is sensible, as for $x=0$ we have $\mathbb{E}[T(0)]=4$, which makes sense since with probability $1/4$ of dropping to $0$, we should expect to reach $0$, on average, in $4$ steps.

**My attempt**:

We have $\forall x$
$$\mathbb{E}[T(x)] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \mathbb{P}[T(x)=n]$$
Let's try to calculate $\mathbb{P}[T(x)=n]$.
The only state that can return in one step is $x=0$, therefore
$$
 \mathbb{P}[T(x)=1] = \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{4}& x = 0 \\
 0& \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
 $$
The only states that can return in two steps are $x=0,1$. For $x=0$ this happens by moving forward to $1$ then falling to $0$, for $x=1$ this happens by falling to $0$ and then moving forward to $1$. So
$$
 \mathbb{P}[T(x)=2] = \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}& x = 0,1 \\
 0& \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
 $$
Now it starts to get interesting. Again, the only states that can return in three steps are $x=0,1,2$ as follows
\begin{align*}
 x=0 \implies& 0\to 1\to 2\to 0 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\\
 x=1 \implies& 1\to 2\to 0\to 1 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\\
  & 1 \to 0 \to 0 \to 1 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\\
 x=2 \implies & 2\to 0 \to 1 \to 2 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2
 \end{align*}
Similarly for $n=4$ we have $x=0,1,2,3$ with
\begin{align*}
 x=0 \implies& 0\to 1\to 2\to 3 \to 0 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3\\
 x=1 \implies& 1\to 2\to 3\to 0\to 1 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3\\
 & 1 \to 2 \to 0 \to 0 \to 1 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\\
 & 1 \to 0 \to 0 \to 0 \to 1 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\\
 x=2 \implies & 2 \to 3 \to 0 \to 1 \to 2 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3\\
 & 2 \to 0 \to 0 \to 1 \to 2 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\\
 x=3 \implies & 3 \to 0 \to 1\to 2 \to 3 \implies \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3
 \end{align*}
After staring at this for about 15 minutes, I realize the formula is probably the following expression. I'm sure one can prove it with induction, but I haven't tried.
$$\mathbb{P}[T(0)=n] = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$
for $x>0$ the probability is
$$\mathbb{P}[T(x)=n] = \sum_{k=x}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}$$
We have two ways to find the expectation, either
$$\mathbb{E}[T(x)] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \mathbb{P}[T(x) = n] =\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{k=x}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}\tag{1} $$
or using the other expectation formula
$$\mathbb{E}[T(x)] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[T(x)>n] = \sum_{n=x+1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[T(x)\ge n]\tag{2a}$$
where the $n=x+1$ starting index is due to the fact that any $x$ needs atleast $x+1$ steps to return to itself.
Note we can write
$$\mathbb{P}[T(x)\ge n] = \sum_{j=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}[T(x)=n] = \sum_{j=n}^\infty \sum_{k=x}^{j-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}$$
Substituting this back into (2a) we get
$$\mathbb{E}[T(x)] = \sum_{n=x+1}^\infty \sum_{j=n}^\infty \sum_{k=x}^{j-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}\tag{2b}$$
I will try to bound it in hopes of showing its finite.
We have the most inner sum
$$\sum_{k=x}^{j-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k} < \sum_{k=x}^{j-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}$$
This is a finite geometric series with initial term $(3/4)^x$, hence its sum is
$$\sum_{k=x}^{j-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k} = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x \frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^j}{1-\frac{3}{4}} = 4 \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x\left[1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^j\right]  $$
Substituting this into the upper bound and relating to (2b) we have
$$\sum_{n=x+1}^\infty \sum_{j=n}^\infty \sum_{k=x}^{j-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k} <4 \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x\sum_{n=x+1}^\infty \sum_{j=n}^\infty \left[1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^j\right] $$

At this point I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. I hope there is a way to patch up this proof.

Comment: You have computed the finite expected return time to $x=0$, and positive recurrence is a class property, so all states that $x=0$ communicates with are positive recurrent.

Comment: @Joe Hmm, that is true. I didn't think of that. Is there a way to calculate the finite expected return time for $x\ne 0$? I am still interested in seeing how the summations work out

Comment: I suspect there is, but I’m not sure what it works out to be. That would be interesting to see, and I’ll vote up anyone who provides a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direct calculation for the return times.

If $\mathbf T(x,y)$ is the time to reach $y$ from $x$, then in this Markov chain we have $\mathbf T(x) = \mathbf T(x,0) + \mathbf T(0,x)$ for all $x>0$: the only way to return to $x$ from $x$ is to go through $0$. We have $\mathbb E[\mathbf T(x,0)] = 4$ by the same argument that $\mathbb E[\mathbf T(0)] = 4$: no matter where we are, we have a $\frac14$ chance of going to $0$ next, so $\mathbf T(x,0) \sim \text{Geometric}(\frac14)$.

Now it remains to compute $\mathbf T(0,x)$, and show that it's finite. We'll do this by induction, treating $\mathbf T(0,0)$ as $0$.

Starting at $0$, let's take $\mathbf T(0,x-1) + 1$ steps: that is, take steps until we reach state $x-1$, and then take $1$ more step. With probability $\frac34$, that next step takes us to $x$ and we're done; with probability $\frac14$, we return to $0$ and waste all our hard work. If the second thing happens, repeat the same procedure again.

The procedure repeats $\mathbf N$ times, where $\mathbf N \sim \text{Geometric}(\frac34)$. Let $\mathbf X_i$ be the number of steps in the $i^{\text{th}}$ iteration: then $\mathbf X_1, \mathbf X_2, \dots$ are i.i.d. and each has the distribution of $\mathbf T(0,x-1)+1$. We have $$\mathbf T(0,x) = \sum_{i=1}^\mathbf N \mathbf X_i.$$
To find the expected value of a random sum of random variables, we have [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation). Here, $\mathbf N$ is independent of $\mathbf X_1, \mathbf X_2, \dots$, so we just need what Wikipedia calls the "basic version", and it tells us that
$$
   \mathbb E[\mathbf T(0,x)] = \mathbb E[\mathbf N] \mathbb E[\mathbf X_1].
$$
Therefore $\mathbb E[\mathbf T(0,x)]$ is finite and equal to $\frac43(\mathbb E[\mathbf T(0,x-1)]+1)$.

Unrolling the recurrence gives $\mathbb E[\mathbf T(0,x)] = (\frac43)^x + (\frac43)^{x-1} + \dots + (\frac43)$ or $\frac{(\frac43)^{x+1}-\frac43}{\frac43 - 1} = 3(\frac43)^{x+1}-4$. This gives $\mathbb E[\mathbf T(x)] = \mathbb E[\mathbf T(0,x)] + 4 = 3(\frac43)^{x+1}$, which is another way to write $4 (\frac43)^x$.